# Is it a problem if the wall portion of a bedroom overlaps with another one in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've just recently learned that a bedroom should contain the walls too, but I only have a 1 tile wide wall between my bedrooms here:

[image: Dwarf Bedrooms]

Is it a problem if these room designations overlap (like in my example)?

Comment: The short answer is: these aren't actually overlapping, so everything's working as expected.

Comment: I mean the areas are overlapping (5x5) as the walls are shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer is:** Bedrooms that share walls simply have walls that exist in both rooms simultaneously (with no loss of value or function). In this sense, there's no problem with shared walls.

**The slightly longer answer is:** Engravings are directional. If you engrave the walls, the engravings will only count for one side of the wall (where the engraver was standing when they completed it, to be precise). If you want each room to have its own engravings, you should ensure the walls don't overlap -- or simply engrave the floors instead!

[Cite Note](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Engraving)

Comment: Oh wait, so I can't engrave a wall from both sides? Does it make sense to have double walls in this case? I'm just trying to maximize the potential happiness a room can produce.

Comment: @AdamArold Material is going to have a bigger effect than whether or not the walls are engraved -- and like I said, just engrave the floors instead. Wealth is easy!~

Comment: Wow, thanks!!!!